# UIImageView stretch in iOS 8 Storyboard Auto Layout

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout, instagram

My `UIImageView` is working perfectly, except it is stretching outside of its `UITableViewCell`

I'm pulling a standard resolution **photo from the Instagram API**, which is 612x612.  I need to put that in a `UIImageView` in a custom `UITableViewCell` **that will use Auto Layout to change the size of the `UIImageView` per the device**.

I'm not sure how this would work in Xcode 6 iOS 8 because what I've tried hasn't worked so far, because the image is just stretching outside the bounds of the device view.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
       [self.imageViewPic setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600.0;

NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", standardResolutionLocal.url];

    __weak MWebListTableViewCellTwo *mCell = api2Cell;
    [mCell.imageViewPic
     sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLInstagram]
     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed issue with UIImageView when used with dynamic cell heught based on auto layout. View is layed out good, but image itself is not stretched as defined by "contentMode" property.

forcing layout for cell before display, somehow fix it, but then it back to non-stretched version after selection so more work is needed. Propably subclass of UITableView will do the job.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```